# Do I need a bill of sale along with title?

Tags: car, new-jersey, title

Long story short, I just bought a car from a private seller in New York. I have the title and he has filled out the information necessary. Do I need to provide the bill of sale as well when I go to DMV? I am from New jersey so I can't find exactly what they need to register it in my name when the title is from New York. Any help is appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 3):

The relevant details are in this document from the NJ Dept. of Motor Vehicles web site:

[NJ Title Requirements](https://www.state.nj.us/mvc/pdf/vehicles/GU30.pdf)

The specifics for your case are, I believe, covered here:

[image: NJ Out of State Vehicle Purchase]

I encourage you to read the entire document to make sure you have everything you need before going there.